# ¿ Como realizar un insert con variables desde un prompt?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Realizando un simple insert en sql seria algo como

insert into gestor.socios (cod_socio,nombre)
values (5,'Ronald');

Mi duda viene al intentar implementarlo en PL/sql y en vez de dar el value, que lo ingrese el usuario por un prompt por lo tanto he llegado al siguiente codigo

```
 accept p1 prompt "Ingresa el cod del socio a agregar";
 accept p2 prompt "Ingresa el nombre del socio a agregar";

declare 
v_codsocio GESTOR.SOCIOS.cod_socio%type :=&p1;
v_nombre GESTOR.SOCIOS.nombre%type :=&p2;
begin
  insert into gestor.socios (cod_socio,nombre)
  values(v_codsocio,v_nombre);
end;
/
```

Sucede que al ejecutar el codigo me da el siguiente error : PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "V_NOMBRE": identificador no válido, Intento colocar la variable v_nombre entre comillas simples al ser un string y tampoco logro realizar el insert.

Alguna sugerencia ? Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo coloca comillas simples sobre el parametro varchar que vas a ingresar, por ejemplo:

v_codsocio GESTOR.SOCIOS.cod_socio%type :=&p1;

v_nombre GESTOR.SOCIOS.nombre%type :=&p2;

donde p1= 1 y p2= 'prueba'

Nota: No olvides poner el commit despues de hacer el insert